# Installing libraries using pip getting "connection time out"

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am trying to install aeneas using the command

```
pip install aeneas
```

and I am getting error as

> Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to 172.16.2.30 timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/aeneas/

Comment: Looks like an internet problem to me. possible packet loss? 
open 'cmd' and run 'ping www.google.com -t' and keep it open while you run the pip again.

Comment: ping is working and I used sudo apt-get update and it is also working.

Comment: So the server hosting the aeneas module might be unreachable. Have you tried installing some other module? Does that work okay?

Comment: Yes, I did but nothing is working.

Comment: It does look like a connection issue to me. Tried to ping 172.16.2.30 but 'Request timed out' for me.

Comment: Its the proxy error. Can you please tell how to remove the proxy from pip?
Like I did remove the proxy from the entire system but I am not getting how to remove the proxy from pip?

Comment: Did it work after removing the proxy? I'm not sure if pip has a way of specifying proxy settings.

Comment: I removed proxy but it is not working.

Comment: I did something and it worked. I don't know how but it worked. What I did was Export the path to anaconda then removed proxy again. I don't know why command was not taken for the whole system at first. Anyway thanksssss

Comment: That's great! You didn't mention earlier that you were using Anaconda. Anyway, looks like you answered your own question :)

Comment: Have you set up a virtual environment for python? Or have two installations of python?

Comment: No, I don't have either of them. I don't know why it worked. And why it didn't work before. Sorry, forgot to mention anaconda :P